# How to modify SQL INSERT query to fail if nested SELECT returns NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of SQL queries that each is an insert statement that gets its values from other tables:

```
insert into table1 values (
        (select tableID from Table1 where Name = 'Name1'),
        (select tableID from Table2 where Name = 'Name2'),
        (select tableID from Table3 where Name = 'Name3')
)
```

If the select statements can't find the value in the table (ie, if there is no 'Name1' in Table1), then that field becomes NULL.

Aside from changing the table design to not allow NULL's, is there a way I can modify my SQL to fail rather than insert NULL, if the nested select statements can't find the specified value?

Comment: Perform the SELECTs separately first storing the values in variables, then it becomes trivial.

Comment: you can set the column to be not NULL. then it should fail if you try to insert NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is store the values in variables initially:

```
DECLARE @tableID1 INT = (SELECT tableID FROM Table1 WHERE Name = 'Name1')
```

Then you can do an

```
IF @tableID1 IS NOT NULL AND @tableID2 IS NOT NULL...
    INSERT...
```

or alternatively an `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT @tableID1 WHERE @tableID1 IS NOT NULL`.

If for some reason you wanted to do it in a single messy statement you could do:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
    (select tableID from Table1 where Name = 'Name1'),
    (select tableID from Table2 where Name = 'Name2'),
    (select tableID from Table3 where Name = 'Name3')
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from Table1 where Name = 'Name1'),
  AND EXISTS (select 1 from Table2 where Name = 'Name2'),
  AND EXISTS (select 1 from Table3 where Name = 'Name3')
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit long winded, but this work and it should be pretty quick.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##table1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##table1

insert into ##table1 values (
    (select tableID from Table1 where Name = 'Name1'),
    (select tableID from Table2 where Name = 'Name2'),
    (select tableID from Table3 where Name = 'Name3')
)

insert into table1
SELECT * FROM ##table1
where tableID is not null
```

You could also just insert it and then,

```
DELETE FROM table1 where tableID is null
```

Comment: It's not the Table that may be null, it's the select statement that retrieves a single ID from each table

Comment: Then why don't you add a IF (SELECT COUNT(*) from ##table1 where tableID is null) > 0 then RAISERROR?

Answer (score 0):

Use update statement

try doing

```
Update Table table_name set id = (select if(Name = NULL, NULL, tableID) from Table1 where Name = 'Name1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with in built sql function to check if inner query is returning null. For example

```
insert into table1 values (
    IFNULL((select tableID from Table1 where Name = 'Name1'),""),
    IFNULL((select tableID from Table2 where Name = 'Name2'),"")
)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but the problem is that I don't want to insert a blank string, I want the query to fail

Comment: I think in this case you can replace blank value with some invalid value for that particular column. Like if a column is expecting integer value then provide string value.

Answer (score 0):

The construct you are looking for is `insert . . . select`.  This allows you to put a `where` clause on the query.  Because your subqueries have to return one row, you can do a `cross join`, which will return at most one row:

```
insert into table1(id1, id2, id3)
    select t1.tableID, t2.tableId, t3.tableId
    from (select tableID from Table1 where Name = 'Name1') t1 cross join
         (select tableID from Table2 where Name = 'Name2') t2 cross join
         (select tableID from Table3 where Name = 'Name3') t3
    where  t1.tableID is not null and t2.tableId is not null and t3.tableId is not null;
```

My guess is that the `where` clause is unnecessary.  `NULL` in your case is probably not the value of the table id, but represents that no row was found.  A `cross join` on a table with no rows returns no rows, so nothing will be inserted.